# Unable to launch Citrix application through JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test a standalone application on the Citrix platform using JMeter. I have installed the Citrix receiver as well as the JMeter ICA plugin for the same. But I am not able to launch the Citrix web form through JMeter.

I tried recording the events using Badboy, but the script is erroring out when trying to export to JMeter as it fails to recognize 'Click' and 'Execute' requests captured in the Badboy script.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A logical description of citrix receiver, app windows are delivered to the client as an image equivalents, and there are no exposed window or browser APIs to interact with.

Options are:

- launch jmeter inside the citrix seasion. jmeter will then be running on citrix and all of the windows API will be interactable.
- open a local browser and paste the url from the citrix server.